# garbage printing value of a key-value pair in python

Tags: python

I have a key-value pair called **data** like below

```
{'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xf7\nP', 'rf_data': 'python', 'source_addr': '\xe5\xbd', 'id': 'rx', 'options': '\x01'}
```

I am interested in retrieving source_addr_long and rf_data for now.

If I do `print data`, it shows the above output

If I do

`print data['source_addr_long']`

the output is a trash like below

```
?@?

P
```

I also did below code

```
for k, v in data.iteritems():
           print k, v
```

and the output is

```
source_addr_long ?@?

P

rf_data python

source_addr ?

id rx


options
```

Seems as the value of the source_addr_long key has escape sequence, the value is not printing properly. Any thoughts on how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried printing `repr(data['source_addr_long'])`

Comment: Where is that data coming from first of all? If you can trace it, you can very well handle it at the source

Comment: If it's network data, maybe `socket.inet_ntop()` ?

Comment: It is a ZigBee network packet. @AustinHastings repr(data['source_addr_long']) solves this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write in python string like `'\x00\x13\xa2'` python actually creates string of 3 bytes

```
>>> len('\x00\x13\xa2')
3
```

with values (in decimal form) `{0, 19, 162}`.
Most of this bytes produce garbage, when you try to write them to terminal.

You can experiment with escaping a little bit and try following command:

```
>>> print '\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'  # it's actually string of 5 chars
```

If you want to print your bytes in human readable form (usually for debugging) it's convenient to use `repr` function in python. In your case

```
>>> data = {'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xf7\nP', 'rf_data': 'python', 'source_addr': '\xe5\xbd', 'id': 'rx', 'options': '\x01'}
>>> print repr(data['source_addr_long'])
'\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xf7\nP'
```